# how to split a .wav file according to lables into multiple fies

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, wav, librosa

how to divide a huge .wav file into multiple .wav files based on the labels marked in wave surfer like from this image

[image]

I want to divide wav files based on upper label values whenever 1 or 0 is seen till that it must be formed as one more .wav file

Comment: What is the question? What have you got so far?

Comment: i wanted to divide a .wav file to multiple chunks based on labels.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't readily import that data into Python, you should check out the speaker diarization functions in the [pyAudioAnalysis](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis) package.